# Lost database on civicrm

Tags: database

I have been working on my membership database on civicrm for the last 4 years and since March I have not been able to access it.
I normally type this on google https://hlpacivicrm.esptest.co.uk/cms/wp-admin
and I get a prompt to put username and password but I get an unrecognised message at the moment.

Comment: I asked the above question about getting my civicrm database back. The link I was using does not work anymore. I contacted our initial providers ESP Projects but they don't work with civicrm anymore and apparently I was using a test site. Please see link above. What is the possibility of recovering the database or getting it to work on the civicrm platform like it did before. It was also embedded on our organisation webiste but was deleted some time ago. Any advice much appreciated, we are a NFP association.
Many thanks
Chandra

Comment: Unless you have a backup of your database somewhere else, the only people who can provide access to it is the company who hosted it for you. The data was all stored on their servers and only they may still have access to this data. If you can get the data back, you can work with someone else who hosts CiviCRM to help you get your site back up and running on their servers. CiviCRM itself is just software and doesn't have your data, so can't help.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be getting certificate errors that lead back to https://espprojects.co.uk

Have you tried contacting your provider who runs this as it looks like it could have been set up as a test site and contract didn't renew in April maybe?

Bari

Comment: Yes, that sounds right, I will contact them, thanks